# Using QGIS Library in Qt Creator

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I wanted to create a GUI in Qt Creator using QGIS libraries. I followed build steps and could build QGIS in Qt Creator. I can open the application from Qt Creator.

I have created a GUI using QT libraries. Now I want to include QGIS libraries into the GUI. And I stuck here. When I include something from QGIS, it gives me several errors. In the below code, if I comment out #include <qgsapplication.h> then it works.

I tried to include paths according to errors but now I am getting "reference to" errors. How can I use QGIS libraries here?

my pro file

```cpp
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = try
INCLUDEPATH += .

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += try.h

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = name_of_the_app

QT += core gui

CONFIG += c++17

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

## QGIS
INCLUDEPATH += /home/koray/dev/cpp/QGIS/build-master-qtcreator/
INCLUDEPATH += /home/koray/dev/cpp/QGIS/build-master-qtcreator/src/core
INCLUDEPATH += /home/koray/dev/cpp/QGIS/src/core
INCLUDEPATH += /home/koray/dev/cpp/QGIS/src/core/settings

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

my cpp file

```cpp
// Qt includes
#include <QApplication>  // create QApplication instance
#include <QPushButton>  // base class of all Qt push buttons
#include <QWidget>   // base class of all Qt widgets
#include <QObject>

// QGIS Includes
include <qgsapplication.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);
 QFont font ("Courier");

 QPushButton button;
 button.setText("\n\nhier ist mein erster Button!");
 button.setWindowTitle(("Hello"));
 button.setToolTip("A tooltip");
 button.setFont(font);
 button.setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("face-smile"));
 button.show();

 return app.exec(); // it tells our QApplication instance to enter the event loop. This loop
                    // regularly checks if there are any user inputs.
}
```

my errors:

```
main.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':

error: undefined reference to `QgsSettingsEntryString::QgsSettingsEntryString(QString const&, QgsSettings::Section, QString const&, QString const&, int, int)'

error: undefined reference to `vtable for QgsSettingsEntryString'

error: undefined reference to `vtable for QgsSettingsEntryBool'
```

and more error like this (below picture)

[image]

Comment: Error messages should be included in the Question as text, which will make it searchable by others with the same issue. Posting an image also means it's less likely to be legible on all devices.